# Print all columns except first using AWK

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a file which contains file list. The file looks like this

```
$ cat filelist
  D       src/layouts/PersonAccount-Person Account Layout.layout
  D       src/objects/Case Account-Record List.object
```

I want to cut first two Columns and print only file names with along directory path. This list is dynamic. File name has spaces in between. So I can't use space as delimiter. How to get this using `AWK` command?

The output should be like this

```
src/layouts/PersonAccount-Person Account Layout.layout
src/objects/Case Account-Record List.object
```

Comment: What options have you tried already? What is your use-case here? It seems a bad practice to write file-names to a file and _later_ parse it meaningfully, when you can do it properly in the first-place

Comment: Is it `git status` output, by any chance?

Comment: Please add sample output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Your data only has 2 columns. What 2 columns are you cutting out?

Comment: Please explain/show what you want. I am tempted to answer `cut -c3- filelist` (columns with 1 char width).

Comment: @TomFenech Yes..It is git status output. Thanks for checking

Comment: @WalterA Thanks. I just want the file names with directories. For example:  
src/objects/Case Account-Record List.object

Comment: So what is the exact command that you're running? What do you want to do in other cases, e.g. when a file has been moved? In this case, there would be two file paths on each line.

Comment: I run the following command "git diff --name-status $lcommit $head" to get the files between last two commits. I will split modified files, deleted using grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> print only file names with along directory path

**awk** approach:

```
awk '{ sub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]][[:space:]]+/,"",$0) }1' filelist
```

The output:

```
src/layouts/PersonAccount-Person Account Layout.layout
src/objects/Case Account-Record List.object
```

**----------**

To extract only ***basename*** of the file:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' filelist
```

The output:

```
PersonAccount-Person Account Layout.layout
Case Account-Record List.object
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Its not working for me! weird! I am running it on RHEL. Here is the screenshot. https://pasteboard.co/GL4tLam.png

Comment: @Ela, It's not weird. That's because your initial input (in the question) has a spaces before the 1st column `D`. But your new input from your screeshot does not have leading spaces. So I will say again: "It works fine" and you may apply my last update for your new input content

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Oops! I didn't notice that. My bad! It works fine. Thanks! If there is no space before 1st column, I think I need to remove first ^[[:space:]] from awk command?

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this once:

```
bash-4.4$ cat filelist |awk '{$1="";print $0}'
 src/layouts/PersonAccount-Person Account Layout.layout
 src/objects/Case Account-Record List.object
```

else if you want to remove 2 columns it would be:

```
awk '{$1=$2="";print $0}'
```

This will produce the below output:

```
bash-4.4$ cat filelist |awk '{$1=$2="";print $0}'                                                                                                                                   
  Account Layout.layout                                                                                                                                                             
  Account-Record List.object
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
awk -F" " '{$1=""; print $0}' filelist | sed 's/^ //c'
```

Here sed is used to remove the first space of the output line.

Answer (score 1):

This will do exactly what you want for your example :

```
 sed -E 's/(.*)([ ][a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9. -]+)/\2/g' filelist
```

#### Explanation :

Its matching your path (including spaces if there were any ) and then replacing the whole line with that one match. Easy peasy lemon squeezy :)

Regards!

Comment: This looks drastically over-complicated. Why not just remove the first part of the line? e.g. `sed -E 's/ *[^ ]+ *//' file`

Comment: Tom Fenech Thats a nice approach too.

Comment: This requires GNU sed and will still fail given a directory with a space in its name.  It will always lead with a space.

Comment: @AdamKatz This does not require GNU SED. It will work in almost any version of SED. Regarding the names of the folders, yeah, you could modify it a little bit in case of spaces in directories names. But on OPs example it does not seem to be spaces on them, but on the file names, which is really common under certain scenarios.

Comment: Neither `sed -E` nor matching groups (e.g. your `\2`) are specified by the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), despite the GNU sed man page's statement of "for portability use POSIX -E")

Comment: @MatiasBarrios Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work when directory has any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A simple grep

```
grep -o '[^[:blank:]]*/.*' filelist
```

That's zero or more non-blank characters followed by a slash followed by the rest of the string.

This will not match any lines that don't have a slash

Comment: This will fail if there are spaces in the directory names.

Comment: True, if "src" is replaced by something with a space. Spaces following the first slash are OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a portable POSIX shell solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat "$@" |while read line; do
  echo "${line#* * }"
done
```

This loops over each line of the given input file(s) (or else standard input) and prints the line without the first two spaces or the text that exists before them.  It is not greedy.

Unlike some of the other answers here, this will preserve spacing (if any) in the rest of the line.

If you want that as a one-liner:

```
while read L < filelist; do echo "${L#* * }"; done
```

---

This will fail if the uppermost directory's name starts with a space.  To work around that, you need to peel away the leading ten characters (which I assume are static):

```
#!/bin/sh

cat "$@" |while read line; do
  echo "${line#??????????}"
done
```

As a one-liner, in bash, this can be simplified by using substrings:

```
while read L < filelist; do echo "${L:10}"; done
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. Its not working. I am getting Infinite loop when I run this!

Comment: When you run which one?  The first & third are scripts and needed to be piped into, for example `no1stcol.sh < filelist`.  I've revised them to accept arguments, so you can run them as I just mentioned or now as `no1stcol.sh filelist otherfile`.